# How to debug Javascript code inside page.evaluate() function in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, debugging, phantomjs

I have a PhantomJS (1.9) script "test.js" (Code taken from PhantomJS docs)-

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://m.bing.com', function(status) {

  var title = page.evaluate(function() {
    // >> I have a breakpoint here, but debugger doesnt stop!
    return document.title;
  });

  console.log(title);
  phantom.exit();

});
```

I am debugging this code with `phantomjs --remote-debugger-port=9000 test.js` and chrome.

I can reach to all code breakpoints except the code inside `page.evaluate()`.
Is there a way to debug it?

Comment: Not breaking using the `debugger` keyword either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is and old question and the phantomJS engine has been legacy for quite some time now, but for all those who has to maintain legacy code just like me, here is a gif I've prepared that shows step by step process of how to debug phantomjs scripts and the page opened inside.
So what you need to do is put a breakpoint in the page script and copy the link of the current browser tab and increase the page number by one. this will attach the debuggger to the inside script and you will be able to debug your code.
you can check out the step by step gif(it was too big to uplo) =>https://gaziedutr-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/ahmet_bekir_urun_gazi_edu_tr/EZUj5yMbgqJIpun7qBdfF5sB3QWWg1r5u3MwayiKsw4Lug?e=PXeS8t

Comment: At the very least you need to upload images to the Stack Overflow Imgur host (use the image uploader in the editor here). Externally hosted images are often deleted after a period of time and only the Imgur host is guaranteed to keep images around forever.

Comment: If it was too big, then find a way to reduce it. Better still: *don’t use a gif animation for what can be described in text*. People with visual impairments can’t see your animation. Search engines can’t index the animation information and so no one will find your help here.